# How to reduce size of UsageAndHealth database?

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have a database UsageAndHealth which is growing fast, I have changed the retention to 3 but how can I purge the data that is already in the database? Can I delete as is or what is the best approach to do it?

I tried to change the max storage for the db but it is not possible until I reduce the size of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After change the retention period, run the “Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Import” timer job and “Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Processing” timer job manually via Central Administration -> Monitoring -> Configure Usage and health data collection-> Log Collection Schedule.

Then the only 3 days log is retained and database has released the space.

Check the blog for more information: [How to reduce the size of logging database OR How to purge the old data from Logging Database](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/manhar/2012/04/17/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-logging-database-or-how-to-purge-the-old-data-from-logging-database/)

Answer (score 0):

did you try to find out the primary source of this extensive growth? (ex., by selecting your logging Database in SSMS -> (Right Click) -> Reports- > Standard Reports -> Disk Usage by Top Tables.)?

Comment: I see in the top dbo.TaskUsage_Partition6 that should be unchecked in the monitoring services?

Comment: I wounder if you could provide a screenshot...?

Comment: Sorry but I can't, I reduce the retention period and ran the timer job manually, it has reduced the size.

Comment: hello Carlos, I didn't mean reducing the retention period, just finding out the source of the extensive growth.